# How would you platonically iterate through data structures

Tags: loops, data-structures

I am very new to coding.

I am looking for a very platonic answer to:
'how do you iterate through date structures'.

p.s I am not taking courses, I am a autodidact.
kindly reply,
Vincent.

Comment: Very unclear and broad question.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the data structure and language you are using.
In pretty much any language you can loop through an array like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterating-arrays-java/).

In Java for example, you can use a [for-each-loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/) to go through all *iterable* data structures.

But this question is kind of useless anyway unless you have a specific language and data structure you want to use. And if you have that, you can look up the answer easily yourself.

Comment: Your answer was not useless.